# Are $G_1$ and $G_2$ isomorphic?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-laplacian

If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two regular graphs on same no. of vertices,with same regularity and have identical Laplacian spectrum, are $G_1$ and $G_2$ isomorphic?

Comment: Not always. See the pair of examples in this section of wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_graph_theory#Isospectral_graphs

Comment: Oops, I now notice that the example I gave was not a pair of regular graphs. They do have the same degree sequence, however (necessarily?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily. Notice that $k$-regular graphs on the same number of vertices have the same Laplacian spectrum if and only if they have the same spectrum on their adjacency matrices. In particular, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix iff $k-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the Laplacian matrix.

On the other hand, [strongly-regular graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_regular_graph) form a rich class of graphs containing many cospectral, non-isomorphic $k$-regular graphs on $n$ vertices, for some values of $n$ and $k$. The smallest example in this class occurs when $n=16$ and $k=6$, and their adjacency matrices can be found at Ted Spence's [site here](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~es/SRGs/16-6-2-2).

Comment: @Caseteels, thanks for the explicit answer. The example at Ted Spence's is smallest in class of strongly-regular graphs. Is it smallest for my question also?

Comment: @sry No, there are definitely smaller ones, but I can't find any explicit examples to show you. I know certain people around here are experts in the area, so they might pipe in soon if they notice this question.

Comment: @Caseteels, lets hope that someone notice this question :)